# rails ActiveAdmin belongs_to admin_inicio_bannerhomes_path()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, belongs-to

i have this

```
class Inicio < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :bannerhomes
end
class Bannerhome < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inicio
end
```

and in activeAdmin have this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Inicio do
    sidebar "Project Details" do
      ul do
        li link_to("Bannerhome", admin_inicio_bannerhomes_path(Inicio))
          #it dont work with Inicio and inicio, why dont work?
        #li link_to("Bannerhome", admin_inicio_bannerhomes_path(1))
          #when i pass 1 it works, but i want every Bannerinicio that belongs to Inicio with id=1
      end
    end
end

ActiveAdmin.register Bannerhome do
    belongs_to :inicio    
end
```

i have one Inicio with id=1, and 4 Bannerhome with id=1,2,3 and 4 and each one have inicio_id=1

i'm follow this doc
http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#belongs_to

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it seems the document lack something. add `:only => :show`, so the sidebar present only in show action, in which `inicio` is available

```
sidebar "Project Details", :only => :show do
  ul do
    li link_to("Bannerhome", admin_inicio_bannerhomes_path(inicio))
  end
end
```